# Puzzled about variable scope in for-loop

Tags: python, scope

This code will raise `NameError: name 'i' is not defined`:

```
for n in range(2, 101):
    for i in range(2, n):
        if n % i == 0:
            break
    if n % i != 0:
        print(n, end=' |')
```

This code will execute without error:

```
n = 97
if True:
    for i in range(2, n):
        if n % i == 0:
            break
    if n % i != 0:
        print(n, end=' |')
```

Could anybody tell why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That has nothing to do with scopes, in fact `for` loops in python do not create their own scopes unless it is in a `list comprehension`. The reason you are getting an error is `i` is not getting created in the first code.

```
for n in range(2,101):
# at first iteration n == 2
    for i in range(2,n):
    # this is equivalent to range(2,2) in first iteration
```

So, there is nothing to iterate on, hence no value is assigned to `i`. And when it goes to `n % i`, it throws `NameError`.

In the second block:

```
for i in range(2, n):
# value if i is 2
```

As `i` has a value, hence defined, it does not throw `NameError`.

Answer (score 4):

When `n` is 2, `range(2,n)` will be an empty list, and so the body of that loop will not execute at all.